# how to solve ssd storage auto full

Tags: ssd, storage

I am using ubuntu 20.04 in 120GB SSD.. after installing ubuntu I have 88.65/120 storage left.. but I am noticing my SSD storage getting auto full like when I am using my computer 2-4 hours it's 88.4/120, a few minutes later 88.2/120, and then 88.0/120 after 4-5 days using my SSD now 87.5/120GB
one thing is I never install new applications.. why is this getting full what is the solution

Comment: Are you using swapspace? what does iostat have to say about what's writing to the disk?

Comment: i dont know what is swapspace,, i usually go to files then i see my ssd is fiiled up by 1/200 mb per hour

Comment: also in this ssd i have installed ubuntu , chrome, discord etc

Comment: Open a terminal and at the prompt type `free -h` and then hit enter. If, on the second line, beside "Swap:" there is a number other than zero, you are using Swapspace. Swapspace is "Virtual memory" - when your computer runs out of RAM, it writes things to your SSD to save them for later.

Comment: swap : total 2.0 Gi    used: 0B  Free:2.0Gi

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: i think i am not using swapspace

Answer (score 0):

You're really asking two questions here:

1. What's using that space?
2. What's the solution?

These questions should be answered in that order, because the first answer will help determine the second.

1. open a terminal window.
2. type `cd /` and hit Enter.
3. type `sudo du -skx * | sort -nr | head` and hit Enter.
4. The response will tell you which directories are using the most diskspace.
5. Investigate, by typing `cd` and the directory name followed by Enter.
6. Press the up-arrow to go back through your command history so that you do not have to retype the long command; it will allow you to investigate the directory tree and figure out what directory is growing over time.

Some tips: at any time, you can start over at step 2.

Chances are good that this is some kind of error log which is growing rapidly somewhere. While you can certainly simply delete the logs ,I do not recommend that. Instead you should look at the contents of the log file, and see what problem it is reporting. Then ask a new question about that. :)

Comment: i seen that google chrome using that space 100 mb per hour.. i use stacer cleaner.. when i clean it remove some files but after few minutes google chrome automatically using a lot of space